# MVP Interactors and Use cases relationship

Tags: android, architecture, mvp, android-mvp

I've been recently trying to understand from an architecture point of view the relationship between the interactors and the use cases in an MVP architecture. My doubt is regarding communication in between parts and what conforms to the MVP standard.

The thing is that I've seen plenty of flow diagrams that contradict each other. Some of them seem to have an interactor per presenter, others seem to have more than one  interactor per presenter (each interactor holding multiple use cases that relate to each other, such as all user-related cases), and others don't seem to use interactors at all and just communicate straight the use cases with the presenter.

My main (and pretty noob) question: **Is it OK from an MVP perspective to have a presenter that communicates with more than one interactor or should just be one interactor per presenter?** There're scenarios where a specific view needs data from various different models, so how would someone handle those?

I'm attaching a flow diagram of a presenter holding two interactors for the sake of completeness of the question and to make my point clear about a presenter that needs to handle different model structures (A user belong to a company, but let's say I also need to show other company information that's only available through the CompanyInteractor and that wouldn't make any sense to duplicate on the UserInteractor). **In case of "one interactor per presenter" is the answer, should that single interactor per presenter communicate with all the different, non-related use cases that the presenter needs?**

Thanks

[image]

PS: Sorry for the chaotic of the flow diagram, 3 minutes using draw.io *shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

As far as there will be only one View then you may use as many interactor as you need. There is no limitation but to avoid boiler plate coding normally one interactor is enough.

In your scenario, you can have a `Base Presenter` from that you can pass or receive request to respective class.

MVP rule:

> separate the presentation(**View**) layer from the logic.